# Filter dateHistogram timeframe in ElasticSearch Java API

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm using DateHistogram aggregation in ElasticSearch, via Java API, but, even if I add a postFilter with a specified from-to timeframe, the query returns data histogram on all documents in the index.

The code I'm using:

```
// note: search is the SearchResponse object    
private RangeFilterBuilder getDateRangeFilter(DateTime dateFrom, DateTime dateTo){
   return FilterBuilders.rangeFilter("@timestamp").from(dateFrom.getMillis()).to(dateTo.getMillis());
}
// In search method
search.setPostFilter(getDateRangeFilter(dateFrom, dateTo));
```

And, the aggregation:

```
search.addAggregation(AggregationBuilders
                      .dateHistogram("histogram")
                      .field("@timestamp")
                      .interval(DateHistogram.Interval.DAY));
```

The DataRangeFilter works well with hits and other aggregations; instead it doesn't work only for dateHistogram aggregation. How can I filter the timeframe of dateHistogram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're using a PostFilter - Aggregation works on the results returned by the query, the PostFilter is occurring too late.

To get your filter to work, use a filtered query (this is probably the one you want) or include a filter as part of the aggregation.

This page on [filtering queries and aggregations](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_filtering_queries_and_aggregations.html) has everything in it you need.

Comment: Thank you, I've switched to a FilteredQuery with the range filter, and it worked.
Regarding performance, is the filteredQuery more memory/CPU consuming, in comparison to postFilter?

Comment: I don't know on the performance, I would think that they should be similar. You'd need to try it out with your data.